# I have a windows application in which we are using a chromium browser to open new html dialog having vuetify components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mfc, vuetify.js

Is there any way we can extend the combobox of Vuetify to open beyond the frame of dialog...>?

[Combobox dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6zow.png)

I was not able to find any useful suggestion which would help me achieve that..as the background is MFC so we have only that much html space..which is inside the chromium browser, so I suppose it's not achieveable, but is there any hack..>?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. The dom nodes would only be rendered inside the web frame.